# How to ignore margins in template: using image

Tags: jasper-reports

I have *JasperReports* template with

```
leftMargin="100" rightMargin="50" topMargin="50" bottomMargin="50"
```

margins. In this template I have `<image>` element. I want to stretch the image to entire page ignoring the page margins.

Please, could you help me to find solution?

```xml
<summary>
    <band splitType="Stretch">
        <image isUsingCache="false" onErrorType="Blank">
            <reportElement uuid="7569" x="0" y="0"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{aaa}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Comment: On what element is the margin?

Answer (score 2):

You can't ignore the `buttom` margin, but the other ones by using a negative position. (Be aware that iReport will not let you enter that in design mode)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5c06ba5e-7f96-4b81-bb6a-fcfe8cc2d13f">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="10"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement uuid="a104abd7-bd73-47c4-a4a1-47efeb32d8bf" x="-20" y="-20" width="594" height="822"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["/home/mor/Desktop/schlachtbeil.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The reason you can't ignore the `bottom` margin is that you cannot expand your `band` to more than `pageHeight -  (topMargin + bottomMargin)`. And every element cant have a `height` larger than `bandHeight - position`

Answer (score 0):

It look like that you have not defined your image element very well.
Here is an example by which you can get whatever you want.

```
<summary>
    <band height="471" splitType="Stretch">
        <image scaleImage="FillFrame">
            <reportElement uuid="45a2de1b-a048-4c65-b5cd-cefabdd39bca" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="471"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["/path/to/your/image"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Hope It will help you. Enjoy.